# How to Draw html css Shapes like Trapezoids

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image]

I want to draw this shape using html, css and put that data in that shape like name of that box and color as shown in image. and how many color have to add like this i want. i was using trapezoid shape but i was not able to add border black for that.

Comment: Hi ! I'm a very bad "css drawer", but I know I can improve my "knowledge" ! Please provide us your attempts, to start with it :)

Comment: this is i tried https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_shapes_trapezoid

Comment: @rohit, have you tried `svg`?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I have svg image of this. but i don't know how to put that  inforamtion in that svg. so i was trying to convert it in html css div. that will be easy to add this text DP and plus icon. colors div at bellow and dynamic information into this like, 02,16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just googled and found an editor (https://editor.method.ac/) for `SVG`. It gives the SVG counterpart for anything you draw there (In the menu View -> Source).

```
<svg width="800" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect stroke-width="6" rx="8" stroke="#666666" id="svg_2" height="93" width="189" y="281" x="209.99998" fill="none"/>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Noto Sans JP" font-size="19" stroke-width="0" id="svg_3" y="357" x="231" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">(02)</text>
  <line stroke="#666666" id="svg_5" y2="229" x2="364" y1="230" x1="243" stroke-width="6" fill="none"/>
  <line id="svg_6" y2="228" x2="246" y1="283" x1="214" stroke-width="6" stroke="#666666" fill="none"/>
  <line id="svg_7" y2="228" x2="245" y1="283" x1="213" stroke-width="6" stroke="#666666" fill="none"/>
  <line id="svg_8" y2="228" x2="362" y1="282" x1="396" stroke-width="6" stroke="#666666" fill="none"/>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Noto Sans JP" font-size="19" stroke-width="0" id="svg_9" y="356" x="285" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">(16)</text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Noto Sans JP" font-size="19" stroke-width="0" id="svg_10" y="357" x="337" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">(00)</text>
  <ellipse stroke="#999999" ry="10" rx="10" id="svg_11" cy="315" cx="247.5" stroke-width="0" fill="#666666"/>
  <ellipse stroke="#999999" ry="10" rx="10" id="svg_12" cy="315" cx="302.5" stroke-width="0" fill="#ff0000"/>
  <ellipse stroke="#999999" ry="10" rx="10" id="svg_13" cy="315" cx="354.5" stroke-width="0" fill="#00a516"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Above is the `SVG` for the following drawing. So you can just edit the `text` element as per your needs. They can be props for your device component.

[image]

Comment: @rohit, check this out!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">
<div>
  <i class="red"></i>
  <span>(23)</span>
</div>
<div>
  <i class="yellow"></i>
  <span>(23)</span>
</div>
<div>
  <i class="green"></i>
  <span>(23)</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>


.top {
    clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 84% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #5e5e5e;
    position: relative;
}

.top:before {
    content: '';
    clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 84% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.bottom {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border: solid 6px #5e5e5e;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.bottom div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}

.bottom i {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.bottom i.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.bottom i.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.bottom i.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUMgd.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).